# Convolution in Continious time

Tags: convolution

[image]

Dear all,

Please find attached image,
I am not able to understand why is the underlined term is to be included.
Shouldn't it be simply the exponential term?

Comment: Paste the link to the image in plain text and someone will edit it in for you

Comment: OK, It must be visible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $u(t-2)$ term needs to be included because the upper limit of the definite integral is $t-2$, not $\infty$:

\begin{align*}
h(t) &= e^{-(t-2)}u(t-2)\\
y(t) &= x(t) * h(t)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t')h(t-t') dt'\\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t')e^{-(t-t'-2)}u(t-t'-2) dt'\\
u(t-t'-2)&= \begin{cases} 1 & t'<t-2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\
y(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{t-2} x(t')e^{-(t-t'-2)}(1) dt' + \int_{t-2}^{\infty} x(t')e^{-(t-t'-2)} (0) dt'\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{t-2} x(t')e^{-(t-t'-2)} dt'.
\end{align*}

Comment: OK Sir, now another question,what if the upper limit was ∞ ? and why is it required that upper limit should be  ∞ ? Please explain.Is it because the convolution integral demands it?

Comment: The upper limit is $\infty$ because of the definition of convolution: you are summing up the effect of impulses at all times $t' \in (-\infty, \infty)$ at the current time $t$. It just so happens that in this particular case, your system only turns on for t>2, i.e. your impulse response is only non-zero for that time interval, so you can equivalently write the convolution integral with the upper limit $t-2$.